# Does getppid Refers to Parent OR Real Parent?

Tags: linux, process, system-calls, pid, libc

I'm confused about the `getppid` syscall in linux.

Does it return the pid of the process that spawned it or the current parent (which could be different if the original parent exited)?

Comment: `getpid` returns the pid of the current process. Not a parent process.

Comment: Are you thinking of `getppid()`?

Comment: @Shawn yes it is

Comment: Processes are nongendered, so they are neither mothers nor fathers of another process, just parents.  By "real parent", I assume you mean the process that spawned it, but I suggest you be more explicit in the future as "real" does not actually describe what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getppid` returns the pid of the parent process at the time of the call.  If a process is reparented (eg: through an explicit syscall to do so or because the parent process exited), the value returned will change accordingly.